# Pandas datetimeindex intraday min, max, first, last and sum

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeindex, stock-data

I have 5 minutes stock data dataframe for multiple days. I am trying to get first, current, min, max values for columns within the day in same index and same dataframe.

I have a pandas dataframe with 5 minutes stock data:

| Index | High | Low | Open | Close | Tvol | Vol |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/3/2022 4:05 | 178.34 | 178.15 | 178.26 | 178.15 | 7418 | 4771 |
| 1/3/2022 4:10 | 178.2 | 177.76 | 178.2 | 177.99 | 12144 | 2522 |
| 1/3/2022 4:15 | 178.08 | 177.9 | 177.93 | 178.08 | 15856 | 2583 |
| 1/3/2022 4:20 | 178.12 | 177.81 | 178.08 | 177.86 | 24365 | 6007 |
| 1/3/2022 4:25 | 178.02 | 178 | 178.02 | 178 | 25898 | 561 |
| 1/3/2022 4:30 | 177.92 | 177.81 | 177.9 | 177.82 | 32159 | 3424 |
| 1/3/2022 4:35 | 177.87 | 177.76 | 177.87 | 177.85 | 35847 | 1748 |
| 1/3/2022 4:40 | 177.88 | 177.77 | 177.85 | 177.77 | 41561 | 3561 |
| 1/3/2022 4:45 | 177.89 | 177.81 | 177.83 | 177.89 | 47914 | 4251 |
| 1/3/2022 4:50 | 178.01 | 177.81 | 177.88 | 178.01 | 52718 | 3159 |
| 1/3/2022 4:55 | 178.06 | 177.92 | 177.96 | 178.06 | 57378 | 3208 |
| 1/3/2022 5:00 | 178.1 | 177.93 | 177.96 | 178.08 | 63095 | 3972 |
| 1/3/2022 5:05 | 178.13 | 177.99 | 178.08 | 177.99 | 70300 | 4856 |
| … |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/3/2022 19:10 | 181.89 | 181.82 | 181.89 | 181.82 | 104641165 | 1909 |
| 1/3/2022 19:15 | 182 | 181.82 | 181.82 | 181.95 | 104645653 | 2864 |
| 1/3/2022 19:20 | 181.94 | 181.88 | 181.92 | 181.88 | 104647370 | 960 |
| 1/3/2022 19:25 | 181.93 | 181.88 | 181.88 | 181.93 | 104648887 | 1233 |
| 1/3/2022 19:30 | 181.94 | 181.75 | 181.94 | 181.75 | 104661587 | 11467 |
| 1/3/2022 19:35 | 181.83 | 181.8 | 181.8 | 181.81 | 104664897 | 2937 |
| 1/3/2022 19:40 | 181.9 | 181.82 | 181.82 | 181.9 | 104671047 | 5214 |
| 1/3/2022 19:45 | 181.93 | 181.82 | 181.85 | 181.93 | 104675034 | 2979 |
| 1/3/2022 19:50 | 182 | 181.85 | 181.93 | 182 | 104679458 | 3673 |
| 1/3/2022 19:55 | 182 | 181.91 | 181.91 | 182 | 104685275 | 4543 |
| 1/3/2022 20:00 | 182 | 181.94 | 181.97 | 181.99 | 104701218 | 14135 |
| 1/4/2022 4:05 | 182.67 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.34 | 10064 | 5364 |
| 1/4/2022 4:10 | 182.5 | 182.3 | 182.39 | 182.3 | 19767 | 5692 |
| 1/4/2022 4:15 | 182.41 | 182.26 | 182.32 | 182.41 | 23957 | 2750 |
| 1/4/2022 4:20 | 182.55 | 182.43 | 182.43 | 182.5 | 30848 | 2888 |
| 1/4/2022 4:25 | 182.61 | 182.52 | 182.57 | 182.61 | 36930 | 3833 |
| 1/4/2022 4:30 | 182.6 | 182.54 | 182.6 | 182.57 | 39015 | 650 |
| 1/4/2022 4:35 | 182.59 | 182.53 | 182.59 | 182.53 | 41933 | 1058 |
| 1/4/2022 4:40 | 182.6 | 182.51 | 182.53 | 182.59 | 45514 | 2682 |
| 1/4/2022 4:45 | 182.87 | 182.6 | 182.61 | 182.87 | 53510 | 4558 |
| 1/4/2022 4:50 | 182.85 | 182.72 | 182.85 | 182.75 | 55486 | 1011 |
| 1/4/2022 4:55 | 182.81 | 182.78 | 182.8 | 182.78 | 57486 | 1117 |
| 1/4/2022 5:00 | 182.95 | 182.78 | 182.78 | 182.87 | 61631 | 1565 |
| … |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/4/2022 19:00 | 179.39 | 179.34 | 179.39 | 179.35 | 99248684 | 507 |
| 1/4/2022 19:05 | 179.35 | 179.31 | 179.35 | 179.33 | 99252312 | 2929 |
| 1/4/2022 19:10 | 179.35 | 179.34 | 179.35 | 179.35 | 99257528 | 4725 |
| 1/4/2022 19:15 | 179.39 | 179.33 | 179.35 | 179.35 | 99259476 | 1475 |
| 1/4/2022 19:20 | 179.38 | 179.31 | 179.38 | 179.31 | 99265392 | 5256 |
| 1/4/2022 19:25 | 179.35 | 179.31 | 179.32 | 179.32 | 99276227 | 9707 |
| 1/4/2022 19:30 | 179.34 | 179.3 | 179.31 | 179.33 | 99278111 | 1460 |
| 1/4/2022 19:35 | 179.33 | 179.3 | 179.33 | 179.32 | 99283303 | 4693 |
| 1/4/2022 19:40 | 179.3 | 179.25 | 179.3 | 179.25 | 99287343 | 2947 |
| 1/4/2022 19:45 | 179.29 | 179.25 | 179.26 | 179.29 | 99290635 | 2509 |
| 1/4/2022 19:50 | 179.35 | 179.25 | 179.25 | 179.29 | 99296217 | 4359 |
| 1/4/2022 19:55 | 179.3 | 179.25 | 179.25 | 179.3 | 99304949 | 7358 |
| 1/4/2022 20:00 | 179.38 | 179.3 | 179.38 | 179.33 | 99310395 | 3873 |

I would like to get for each dataframe index minimum of low, maximum for high, first for open, last for close and sum for vol columns from the start of the day from current index.

Expecting following result:

| Index | High | Low | Open | Close | Tvol | Vol | FROM_DAY_START_HIGH | FROM_DAY_START_LOW | FROM_DAY_START_OPEN | FROM_DAY_START_CLOSE | FROM_DAY_START_VOL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/3/2022 4:05 | 178.34 | 178.15 | 178.26 | 178.15 | 7418 | 4771 | 178.34 | 178.15 | 178.26 | 178.15 | 4771 |
| 1/3/2022 4:10 | 178.2 | 177.76 | 178.2 | 177.99 | 12144 | 2522 | 178.34 | 177.76 | 178.26 | 177.99 | 7293 |
| 1/3/2022 4:15 | 178.08 | 177.9 | 177.93 | 178.08 | 15856 | 2583 | 178.34 | 177.76 | 178.26 | 178.08 | 9876 |
| 1/3/2022 4:20 | 178.12 | 177.81 | 178.08 | 177.86 | 24365 | 6007 | 178.34 | 177.76 | 178.26 | 177.86 | 15883 |
| 1/3/2022 4:25 | 178.02 | 178 | 178.02 | 178 | 25898 | 561 | 178.34 | 177.76 | 178.26 | 178 | 16444 |
| 1/3/2022 4:30 | 177.92 | 177.81 | 177.9 | 177.82 | 32159 | 3424 | 178.34 | 177.76 | 178.26 | 177.82 | 19868 |
| 1/3/2022 4:35 | 177.87 | 177.76 | 177.87 | 177.85 | 35847 | 1748 | 178.34 | 177.76 | 178.26 | 177.85 | 21616 |
| 1/3/2022 4:40 | 177.88 | 177.77 | 177.85 | 177.77 | 41561 | 3561 | 178.34 | 177.76 | 178.26 | 177.77 | 25177 |
| 1/3/2022 4:45 | 177.89 | 177.81 | 177.83 | 177.89 | 47914 | 4251 | 178.34 | 177.76 | 178.26 | 177.89 | 29428 |
| 1/3/2022 4:50 | 178.01 | 177.81 | 177.88 | 178.01 | 52718 | 3159 | 178.34 | 177.76 | 178.26 | 178.01 | 32587 |
| 1/3/2022 4:55 | 178.06 | 177.92 | 177.96 | 178.06 | 57378 | 3208 | 178.34 | 177.76 | 178.26 | 178.06 | 35795 |
| 1/3/2022 5:00 | 178.1 | 177.93 | 177.96 | 178.08 | 63095 | 3972 | 178.34 | 177.76 | 178.26 | 178.08 | 39767 |
| 1/3/2022 5:05 | 178.13 | 177.99 | 178.08 | 177.99 | 70300 | 4856 | 178.34 | 177.76 | 178.26 | 177.99 | 44623 |
| … |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/3/2022 19:10 | 181.89 | 181.82 | 181.89 | 181.82 | 104641165 | 1909 | 182.88 | 177.5 | 178.26 | 181.82 | 89930187 |
| 1/3/2022 19:15 | 182 | 181.82 | 181.82 | 181.95 | 104645653 | 2864 | 182.88 | 177.5 | 178.26 | 181.9599 | 89933051 |
| 1/3/2022 19:20 | 181.94 | 181.88 | 181.92 | 181.88 | 104647370 | 960 | 182.88 | 177.5 | 178.26 | 181.88 | 89934011 |
| 1/3/2022 19:25 | 181.93 | 181.88 | 181.88 | 181.93 | 104648887 | 1233 | 182.88 | 177.5 | 178.26 | 181.93 | 89935244 |
| 1/3/2022 19:30 | 181.94 | 181.75 | 181.94 | 181.75 | 104661587 | 11467 | 182.88 | 177.5 | 178.26 | 181.75 | 89946711 |
| 1/3/2022 19:35 | 181.83 | 181.8 | 181.8 | 181.81 | 104664897 | 2937 | 182.88 | 177.5 | 178.26 | 181.81 | 89949648 |
| 1/3/2022 19:40 | 181.9 | 181.82 | 181.82 | 181.9 | 104671047 | 5214 | 182.88 | 177.5 | 178.26 | 181.9 | 89954862 |
| 1/3/2022 19:45 | 181.93 | 181.82 | 181.85 | 181.93 | 104675034 | 2979 | 182.88 | 177.5 | 178.26 | 181.9399 | 89957841 |
| 1/3/2022 19:50 | 182 | 181.85 | 181.93 | 182 | 104679458 | 3673 | 182.88 | 177.5 | 178.26 | 182 | 89961514 |
| 1/3/2022 19:55 | 182 | 181.91 | 181.91 | 182 | 104685275 | 4543 | 182.88 | 177.5 | 178.26 | 182 | 89966057 |
| 1/3/2022 20:00 | 182 | 181.94 | 181.97 | 181.99 | 104701218 | 14135 | 182.88 | 177.5 | 178.26 | 181.99 | 89980192 |
| 1/4/2022 4:05 | 182.67 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.34 | 10064 | 5364 | 182.67 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.34 | 5364 |
| 1/4/2022 4:10 | 182.5 | 182.3 | 182.39 | 182.3 | 19767 | 5692 | 182.67 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.3 | 11056 |
| 1/4/2022 4:15 | 182.41 | 182.26 | 182.32 | 182.41 | 23957 | 2750 | 182.67 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.41 | 13806 |
| 1/4/2022 4:20 | 182.55 | 182.43 | 182.43 | 182.5 | 30848 | 2888 | 182.67 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.5 | 16694 |
| 1/4/2022 4:25 | 182.61 | 182.52 | 182.57 | 182.61 | 36930 | 3833 | 182.67 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.61 | 20527 |
| 1/4/2022 4:30 | 182.6 | 182.54 | 182.6 | 182.57 | 39015 | 650 | 182.67 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.57 | 21177 |
| 1/4/2022 4:35 | 182.59 | 182.53 | 182.59 | 182.53 | 41933 | 1058 | 182.67 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.53 | 22235 |
| 1/4/2022 4:40 | 182.6 | 182.51 | 182.53 | 182.59 | 45514 | 2682 | 182.67 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.59 | 24917 |
| 1/4/2022 4:45 | 182.87 | 182.6 | 182.61 | 182.87 | 53510 | 4558 | 182.87 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.87 | 29475 |
| 1/4/2022 4:50 | 182.85 | 182.72 | 182.85 | 182.75 | 55486 | 1011 | 182.87 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.75 | 30486 |
| 1/4/2022 4:55 | 182.81 | 182.78 | 182.8 | 182.78 | 57486 | 1117 | 182.87 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.78 | 31603 |
| 1/4/2022 5:00 | 182.95 | 182.78 | 182.78 | 182.87 | 61631 | 1565 | 182.95 | 182.1 | 182.22 | 182.87 | 33168 |
| … |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/4/2022 19:00 | 179.39 | 179.34 | 179.39 | 179.35 | 99248684 | 507 | 183.38 | 179.12 | 182.22 | 179.35 | 77209201 |
| 1/4/2022 19:05 | 179.35 | 179.31 | 179.35 | 179.33 | 99252312 | 2929 | 183.38 | 179.12 | 182.22 | 179.33 | 77212130 |
| 1/4/2022 19:10 | 179.35 | 179.34 | 179.35 | 179.35 | 99257528 | 4725 | 183.38 | 179.12 | 182.22 | 179.35 | 77216855 |
| 1/4/2022 19:15 | 179.39 | 179.33 | 179.35 | 179.35 | 99259476 | 1475 | 183.38 | 179.12 | 182.22 | 179.35 | 77218330 |
| 1/4/2022 19:20 | 179.38 | 179.31 | 179.38 | 179.31 | 99265392 | 5256 | 183.38 | 179.12 | 182.22 | 179.31 | 77223586 |
| 1/4/2022 19:25 | 179.35 | 179.31 | 179.32 | 179.32 | 99276227 | 9707 | 183.38 | 179.12 | 182.22 | 179.32 | 77233293 |
| 1/4/2022 19:30 | 179.34 | 179.3 | 179.31 | 179.33 | 99278111 | 1460 | 183.38 | 179.12 | 182.22 | 179.33 | 77234753 |
| 1/4/2022 19:35 | 179.33 | 179.3 | 179.33 | 179.32 | 99283303 | 4693 | 183.38 | 179.12 | 182.22 | 179.32 | 77239446 |
| 1/4/2022 19:40 | 179.3 | 179.25 | 179.3 | 179.25 | 99287343 | 2947 | 183.38 | 179.12 | 182.22 | 179.25 | 77242393 |
| 1/4/2022 19:45 | 179.29 | 179.25 | 179.26 | 179.29 | 99290635 | 2509 | 183.38 | 179.12 | 182.22 | 179.29 | 77244902 |
| 1/4/2022 19:50 | 179.35 | 179.25 | 179.25 | 179.29 | 99296217 | 4359 | 183.38 | 179.12 | 182.22 | 179.29 | 77249261 |
| 1/4/2022 19:55 | 179.3 | 179.25 | 179.25 | 179.3 | 99304949 | 7358 | 183.38 | 179.12 | 182.22 | 179.3 | 77256619 |
| 1/4/2022 20:00 | 179.38 | 179.3 | 179.38 | 179.33 | 99310395 | 3873 | 183.38 | 179.12 | 182.22 | 179.33 | 77260492 |

I have realisation with rolling apply but it is very slow. For volume columns I have the solution with groupby and cumsum.

Thank you.

Comment: Please format your example and make it minimal, you'll need to group by date, then aggregate with the desired functions, something like: `df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['date_column']).dt.normalize()).agg(['min', 'max', 'first', 'last', 'sum'])`

Comment: mozway, thank you for your reply, df["Low"].groupby(df.index.date).agg(['min']) returns daily data. However, I am looking for still 5 minutes data, but aggregation starts from the beggining of the day in current index